# Find an exponential formula with two inputs and one output

Tags: interpolation, least-squares

I'm starting with a pretty much blank understanding of calculus and trigonometry.  I'm not even sure either one is necessary here.  I'm familiar with basic Algebra.  I'm interested in learning more about these subjects, but most of the articles I've come across start at a level that is too far over my head for me to understand it.  I assume an understanding of either [Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) or [Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)(perhaps both) would help me to solve this easily, but my existing knowledge isn't enough for me to decipher those texts.

If you could point me toward a resource that could help me build to an understanding of either of those subjects, I would greatly appreciate it(assuming I'm correct in my assumption above).  Even better though, if you could provide an answer that would satisfy the below situation, I would be ecstatic. :D

Basic premise:
A product of the combination of base(b) and work(w) results in a predictable gain(g).

Here is a small subset of the data I have(b:w,  g):

```
    111:100,  1
    863439:50,  3137
    7000:1000,  231768
    200000:4000,  11845572
    35000:6019,  18190000
```

I've intentionally included a wide range within this subset.  As you can see, increasing the magnitude of work(w) seems to have a much larger effect than increasing the magnitude of base(b).

Comment: Your list is unreadable.  The commas and semicolons seem random.  Is this supposed to be lists of 3.  Can you write it cosistantly in groups of three as (111,100:1)(863,439:50), (3,137:7)(000, 1:000)etc.?

Comment: Done.  Sorry.  I got distracted halfway through trying to make it a bit better from the first iteration, and didn't finish the changes.  This should be much more coherent now.

Comment: Interpolation and least squares work best on data that are basically linear. These data clearly aren't linear. There are ways to fix that, but it basically comes down to a game of guess-the-function where least squares just helps you pin down a few constants in the formula. Any clues about how the function might look would help. Alternatively, make a table where each row is labeled with a $b$ value and each column with a $w$ value, and fill in the resulting $g$ value in each place in the table. It will be easier to see patterns that way.

Comment: Well, this definitely helps.  It provides a solid place to work from.  The data within each column and row of the resulting table should be linear(right?), so maybe I can start there and work closer to a formula solution.  Should I try to put up a copy of the full table here somehow?  If so, what is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input data**
$$
\begin{array}{rrr}
 x & y & z \\\hline
 111 & 100 & 1 \\
 863439 & 50 & 3137 \\
 7000 & 1000 & 231768 \\
 200000 & 4000 & 11845572 \\
 35000 & 6019 & 18190000 \\
\end{array}
$$

**Functional form**

$$
z(x,y) = a x^{b} y^{c}
$$

**Least squares problem**

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
\end{array}
\right]_{LS}
=
\left\{
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
\end{array}
\right]
\in\mathbb{C}^{3} \colon \,
\sum_{k=1}^{5} \left(
  z_{k} = a x_{k}^{b} y_{k}^{c}
\right)^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$

**Least squares solution**

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
\end{array}
\right]_{LS}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
 0.013405 \\
 0.249977 \\
 2.11573 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Error vector
$$
r = z - a_{LS} x^{b_{LS}} y^{c_{LS}} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 -740.322 \\ 1531 \\ -40902.1 \\ 4742.05 \\ 8668.41 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Total error $r^{2} = 1.77\times 10^9$

The plot below shows $r^{2}$ as a function of $b$ and $c$ with $a$ fixed at $a_{LS}$.

[image: dot]